# UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python

```
prod_3 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "c3-a1.tsHeadline500Medium.c3-b9").text
print(prod_3)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Максим\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\main.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(prod_3)
  File "C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Возможно это связанно с тем, что в строке `<span class="c3-a1 tsHeadline500Medium c3-b9">337&thsnip;₽</span>` линий символы &thsnip.
Подскажите, как исправить ошибку и вывести только цену ?
Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки с трэйсбэком.

Comment: Это ещё не полный текст ошибки

Comment: Хотя упоминание cp1251 в тексте ошибки намекает, что используемая вами консоль не поддерживает юникод (и к парсингу это никакого отношения не имеет)

Comment: @andreymal, т. е. в питоне на консоль можно выводить только поддерживаемые символы?